# Unable to run a python3 script in CentOs7 [with python2.7] via cronjob

Tags: linux, centos, bash, cron, python

I have been trying to deal with this strage problem all morning.

I have a simple `crawler.py` file, which contans a code that can only run under python3 to be exact under python3.3 evenrionment

Now, my default CentOs7 machine comes with python2.7 so, I am forced to switch using python3 to run my script, example:

```
scl enable python33 bash
```

example.

```
[root@bt py]# python -V
Python 2.7.5
[root@bt py]# scl enable python33 bash
[root@bt py]# python -V
Python 3.3.2
```

as you can see, it changed the version after which, I can run simple run `crawler.py` without a problem as easy as `python crawler.py`.

But, I need this python file to run via cron, at specific time of the week.

The problem is that once I log out of my VPS, python2.7 becomes the default and if cron triggers it, it won't run. 
For this I thought I should use the python3 binary instead of just `python ..` so, I tried with the following

```
/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3 crawler.py
```

But, it seems the binary does not appear unles you run `scl enable python33 bash`

you can see this for yourself,

```
[root@bt ~]# whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
[root@bt ~]# scl enable python33 bash
[root@bt ~]# whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/include/python2.7 /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3m /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3-config /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3m-config /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

The binary, only appears after python33 is called via `scl`. So, all the time I have to tell cron to somehow execute `scl enable python bash` command so my python3 scripts runs without issues.

So, I created a bash file as

```
#!/bin/bash 
$(scl enable python33 bash)
python crawler.py 
# alternatively I tried the below solution also. 
# /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3 crawler.py
```

But, once bash executes the first command it exits the process or spawns other processes. even tried putting this

```
scl enable python33 bash && python crawl.py
```

also

```
scl enable python33 bash && /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3 crawl.py
```

So, in a nutshell, it seem there is no way to run a python3 script via cronjob, if you have anything but python3 as default in your machine.

Comment: Why do you keep calling bash instead of the script you really want to run?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ah, if you mean the `#!/bin/bash` because, the there is an if/else statement, as the actual python files are more than one, so I need something like `bash crawl.py abc` and `bash crawl.py xyz` those commands are sent from cron, but in the bash I need to use if/else to indentify the argument .. so, to simply put it, the bash has conditionals.

Comment: @ANW: See answer to **your** question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36245769/3776858

Comment: @Cyrus This is completely different, please read this question if you want.

Comment: To clarify, I accepted that answer too soon, without realizing that `/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3 script.py` does not work once you log out

Comment: It's useful to understand the first sentence from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36245957/3776858) to your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36245769/3776858).

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned that here `"But, once bash executes the first command it exits the process or spawns other processes."` That is not the issue, it's more complex than process spawning.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it correctly, then you want to use cron to run a bash script, in which a call to python results in the scl'ed python33 version.

I just implemented and tested that here, on a Scientific Linux box with python33 from scl, just as in your case.

Create a bash script:

```
$ cat /home/username/mybashfile.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo `date` >> /home/username/pythonversionfile
python --version >> /home/username/pythonversionfile 2>&1
```

and create a cron entry like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/scl enable python33 'bash -c /home/username/mybashfile.sh'
```

Which means you call scl to use the python33 environment, which calls bash, directly with the call to the script you created before.

This works nicely and gives me the following output:

```
$ tail pythonversionfile 
Wed Mar 30 17:36:01 CEST 2016
Python 3.3.2
Wed Mar 30 17:37:02 CEST 2016
Python 3.3.2
Wed Mar 30 17:38:01 CEST 2016
Python 3.3.2
Wed Mar 30 17:39:01 CEST 2016
Python 3.3.2
Wed Mar 30 17:40:01 CEST 2016
Python 3.3.2
```

So you can see that the bash script is called by cron every minute, and inside the bash script the environment is correctly set such that python results in python 3.3.2 being called.

Answer (score 1):

Cronjob (example):

```
0 1 * * * scl enable python33 'python /path/to/crawl.py'
```

---

Syntax of scl:

> scl enable software_collection... 'command...'

[Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/1/html-single/1.0_Release_Notes/index.html#sect-Installation_and_Usage-Use)

Comment: Yup - just worked this out myself, mildly interesting too.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it does not work. I have tried to this before, and tried it now just to be sure, I see nothing. For example, the `crawl.py`  does not seem to get executed. To be sure I did manually `scl enable python33` the `python crawl.py` and I can see this works, and if I paste `scl enable python33 'python p.py'` and execute it it works, but not from cron. Checked `/var/log/cron` there is no errors, or permission issues.

Comment: Try this step: `0 1 * * * scl enable python33 'python --version' >/tmp/version.txt`

Comment: You can check this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NXEV6k34) as you can see, the `version.txt` gets created but nothing is written on it, simultaneously I get notice from cronjob (guessing!)  that says "`You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root`" and when I check the mail, I can see the python version.

Comment: Okay, python wrote its output to stderr.

Comment: Okay, python (version 3.3) works. Use full path to `crawl.py` in your cronjob. Example: `/home/anw/subdir/crawl.py`. Avoid a relative path. Example: `./subdir/crawl.py`

Comment: @ANW: Have you tried it with full path?

Comment: Nope, I haven't.

Comment: I had found a workaround and didn't have time to try both answers, but now I did.